# Homomorphisms of the integers under addition

Tags: group-theory, functions

I am solving the following textbook question:

Consider the group $\Bbb Z$ given by the integers under addition. Determine which
of the following functions $f : \Bbb Z \to  \Bbb Z$ are homomorphisms (justify your answer).

(1) $f(z) = 2z$.
(2) $f(z) = 5z + 2$.
(3) $f(z) = -z$.

Is it correct to proceed like $f(x+y)=2(x+y)=2x+2y=f(x)+f(y)$ therefore (1) is a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, that verifies 1 is a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is right.

(2) is not. ( $f(x+y)=5(x+y)+2\not=5x+2+(5y+2)=f(x)+f(y)$)

(3) is right. ($f(x+y)=-(x+y)=-x+(-y)=f(x)+f(y)$)